# How to convert image tensor in to numpy array in tensorflow?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow, opencv

I am training a CNN to generate images. The type of all the images are tensors. I want them to be converted into numpy arrays then I can process them using opencv.

I know about the `.numpy()` method, it converts my tensor into an numpy array but the shape is still tensor. I can't get it to work in cv2.

Here is my code:

```
p=model_(x) 
s=p.numpy()
print(s.shape)
cv2.imwrite("hello.jpg",s)
```

(1, 183, 275, 3), this is the shape of the array generated using `.numpy()`, how can I change its shape to retain output image?

Answer (score 3):

You need to get rid of the first dim (batch), just use slicing with `reshape`.

```
s=p.numpy()
print(s.shape)
cv2.imwrite("hello.jpg",s.reshape(s.shape[1:]))
```